# How to make a Php response to Objective-C (iPhone)?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode, response

My problem is that I don't know how to send the data that I find (with Select From Where) in PHP to Objective-C. I know I need to make a dataset but how do I do it? Some people say I should use JSON but I can't find any solution. Indeed, I don't know how to make a response in PHP? Can anyone help me?

This is my PHP code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("url","username","password");

if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
    mysql_select_db("Appiness", $con);

$bilgi= mysql_query("SELECT c_id FROM country WHERE c_name='$country'");

while($sutun= mysql_fetch_array($bilgi))
{
    echo $sutun["c_id"];
}

mysql_close($con);
```

This is my Objective-C code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someurl"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:year1 forKey:@"year"];
[request setPostValue:appy_level forKey:@"appy_level"];
[request setPostValue:reasons forKey:@"reasons"];
[request setPostValue:country forKey:@"country"];
[request setPostValue:city forKey:@"city"];
[request setPostValue:sex forKey:@"sex"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    

    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: One option is to have a look at NSXMLParser http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i   and have your php file return an xml string.  (build the xml string like... `$output += "<country_id>" + $sutun["c_id"] + "</country_id>"`

Comment: thanks now i am checking thanks for your reply

Comment: @Danny Togaer - This is very unsafe code you have in your PHP as well.  Very vulnerable to SQL injection.  I suggest you read up on that before you put anything in the real world otherwise you could be asking for a whole world of pain.

Comment: thanks nick i know this is not the real one i mean this code is not work in the server i am just trying to connect and than complete all project but of course thanks for consern mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know xml parsing you can response with xml as follows using php code.

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    $error_respond ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><result>failure</result>';
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $return_val='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
        $id = $_POST['userid'];
        $return_val=$return_val.'<UserDetails>';

        $selusersql ="select * from users where userid = ".$id;
        $selusertrs  = mysql_query($selusersql);
        $selusernum = mysql_num_rows($selusertrs);
        while($userrow = mysql_fetch_array($selusertrs))
        {
            $return_val=$return_val.'<UserID>'.$userrow['User_ID'].'</UserID>';
            $return_val=$return_val.'<UserName>'.$userrow['User_Name'].'</UserName>';
            $return_val=$return_val.'<Email>'.xmlentities($userrow['User_Email']).'</Email>';
        }
        $return_val=$return_val.'</UserDetails>';
        echo $return_val;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $error_respond;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Sample Output of above code will be (assuming user id posted 1 and details stored in db is as follows)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserDetails>
<UserID>1</UserID>
<UserName>DummyUser</UserName>
<Email>Dummy@Dummy.com</Email>
</UserDetails>
```

if error occurred like someone tried to call your url from browser directly i.e. request method is not `POST` so we will return following response showing error. (I believe post is better than get).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>failure</result>
```

Now last important part is you have to parse this response according to your requirement. Search around and you will get xmlparsing demo like how to do xml parsing in iphone.

Comment: thanks alot jennis i am working now for xml i guess i am needing it alot than this thanks alot

Comment: @Danny Glad it helped you. Stackoverflow is the place where you can get most of answers helping you. Thax to community.